# SSRS syntax error with countdistinct iif

Tags: sql, reporting-services, syntax-error, ssrs-2014

I have an SSRS report where I want to count specific results from the larger query (Overall Total - then of those total "Open" and total "Closed").  I'm trying to use the expression:

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!CaseStatusCode.Value='OPEN', Fields!CaseID.Value, Nothing))
```

But whenever I run the report I get:

> There is a syntax error in the Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox24.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’: ‘)’ expected.

I've added and removed multiple `)` but the error persists.  I've also tried the expression in different textboxes and the error continues (just changing the name of the textbox it's in). What am I missing?

Comment: Solved it.  Apparently I am supposed to use " instead of '.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.  Apparently I am supposed to use " instead of '.  Corrected code below.

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!CaseStatusCode.Value="OPEN", Fields!CaseID.Value, Nothing))
```